# How to use dbus and NetworkManager to activate a connection

Tags: java, dbus, networkmanager

as per my previous SO questions, I'm still working on controlling NetworkManager via dbus from a Java application.  I want to activate an existing wireless connection so here's my code, stripped as much as possible of irrelevancies:

```
DBusInterface iface = ...;
var nmIface = (NetworkManagerIface) instance.getRemoteObject(NetworkManagerIface._NM_IFACE, NetworkManagerIface._NM_PATH, NetworkManagerIface.class);
System.out.println("Attempting connection to " + iface.getObjectPath());
var result = nmIface.ActivateConnection(new DBusPath(iface.getObjectPath()), new DBusPath("/"), new DBusPath("/"));
System.out.println("Activate Connection " + result.getPath());
```

where `NetworkManagerIface` is [here](https://github.com/michaelNGV/kk-dbus-nm-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/NetworkManagerIface.java).
This runs alright and prints:

```
Attempting connection to /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4
Activate Connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
```

so it looks like the call to `ActivateConnection` worked, inasmuch as it returned something sensible.  However, the command `nmcli c show` shows the connection as **not** in-use.

NetworkManager holds eight connections in our system:

```
# dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings string:Connections
method return time=1575940954.061910 sender=:1.8 -> destination=:1.70 serial=9361 reply_serial=2
   variant       array [
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/7"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/8"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1"
         object path "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/6"
      ]
```

The existing connection is the wired (ethernet) connection and I want to add a wireless connection.  Why doesn't my `ActivateConnection` call do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the `ActivateConnection` call returns success, but afterwards the profile is not actually activating/activated, it stands to reason that the activation shortly after failed.

Look at NetworkManager's logfile to understand why the activation failed. Possibly enable `level=TRACE` logging, see https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/contrib/fedora/rpm/NetworkManager.conf#n28 for hints about logging.

You could also run `nmcli monitor` in another terminal, to get an idea what happens.

> The existing connection is the wired (ethernet) connection and I want to add a wireless connection

You want to add a connection profile? That is not what `ActivateConnection` does. See `AddConnection` and the D-Bus API in general: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/spec.html

> Why doesn't my ActivateConnection call do this?

Sorry, I don't understand. Do what?